# How to copy files in powershell that contain variable in name?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files that match an environment identifier set to a variable. The output of the command looks good until in include the `where-object` section. I only want to copy files that contain the string in the `$environmenttype` string.

What do I need to change to get the `where-object` to operate correctly?

```
$environmenttype = "dev"
Write-Output "environmenttype is set to $environmenttype"
Get-ChildItem -path "\content" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name | Where-Object {$_ -contains "$environmenttype"} | Copy-Item -Path "C:\newdir"
```

Comment: `$_ -contains "$environmenttype"` -> `$_ -like "*$environmenttype*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I'd write it:

```
Get-ChildItem "\content" -File | where BaseName -like "*$environmenttype*" | Copy-Item "C:\newdir"
```

I am using the simplified version of `Where-Object` and the `-like` operator/parameter and a wildcard pattern (note the asterisks `*`).

`BaseName` is the name of the file without extension.

I omitted some implicit parameter names, and added the `-File` switch to include files only.

(Note that the path in `Copy-Item` is set by the pipeline, so the parameter is actually `-Destination`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use match predicate, which supports variable usage.

```bsh
$filter = "ansi" 
Get-ChildItem -path "c:\dev\" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "$filter"} | Copy-Item -Destination C:\dev\testFolder
```